# Determining the time dependent wave function for the first two stationary states in infinite square well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I am working on problem 2.5 in Griffiths *Quantum Mechanics*, and I am trying to work through part b. This question provides that a particle is in the infinite square well and has its initial wave function as an even mixture of the first two stationary states: $$\psi(x,0) = A[\psi_1(x) + \psi_2(x)]$$
part a asks for normalization, which gives us $$A = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$ then part b asks for $\psi(x,t)$.

So, the confusion I am having is with the constants $c_n$. In the section prior to this, on the infinite square well, my understanding is that we can find the solution of the time-independent Schrodinger equation, tack on the relevant time dependence, and write any solution as a linear combination of the product of the solution to the time-independent solution and the time dependence term.

I tried to find $c_n$ by using that $$c_n = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{a}}\int _0^a\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{a}x\right)\psi (x,0)dx$$ and to note that since these are the first and second stationary states, we know that they take the form $$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{a}}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{a}x\right)dx$$ Then, we compute the above integral to find $c_n$. Then, I planned to write the general solution appealing to the formula $$\psi(x,t) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}c_n\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{a}}\int _0^a\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{a}x\right)e^{-i\left(\frac{n^2\pi^2\hbar}{2ma^2}t\right)}dx$$However, the solution just takes the states, tacks on the time dependence, and that's it. My question is why we don't need to solve for the $c_n$ constants here?

To clarify, the solution presents the following: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}e^{-i\omega t}\left[\sin{\frac{\pi x}{a}} + \sin{\frac{2\pi x}{a}}e^{-3i\omega t}\right]$$

Where do the $c_n$ constants go/why don't we need them?

Comment: did you try solving for the $c_n$’s?  Maybe they are all the same…

Comment: @ZeroTheHero yes, i did, but maybe i messed up the integral the first time I did the problem. i left a comment on the answer posted here asking if that was correct which was me trying to continue on with that hint. maybe you can tell me if this is what you mean?

Comment: why does everyone on this website just assume nobody does anything - I cant post anything without a downvote or some negative feedback and I'm legit just trying to self-learn quantum mechanics. this sucks.

Comment: unfortunately for you this is not a site for assignment help.  See https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14122/36194 as the most recent version of the consensus.

Comment: im not doing an assignment ??????? @ZeroTheHero and as i just said i followed up on the hint and just want to know if that is what the person meant and if this is why those constants are dropped?

Comment: FYI you can read off the coefficients directly from your specific $\psi(x,0)$: there is no computation to do, as suggested by @AccidentalTaylorExpansion.  Of course you can plow forward using the general expression.  (And no the constants are not dropped: they are evaluated.  The hint is enough.)

Comment: whether or not *you* are doing an assignment is not the point.  It’s still an assignment question.

Comment: okay i understand. :( can you still tell me if the logic I provided in accidentaltaylorexpansion's answer comment section is right? or is that also not allowed...

Comment: it’s *almost* correct.  You have some algebra error.  Your sanity check is that you should have $\sum_n \vert c_n\vert^2=1$

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct but you're missing the final step.

What happens when you calculate $c_n$, i.e. when you evaluate the integral? In this case $\psi(x,0)$ is completely known and it can be calculated. Which values of $c_n$ are non-zero?

Is there a way you can read off $c_n$ just by looking at the form of $\psi(x,0)$?

Also: don't forget your $dx$'s, it will bite you in the butt later

---

Edit: I will put my response in my answer otherwise it will get too long. You are indeed trying to calculate
$$c_n=\int\mathrm d x\,\psi_n^*(x)\psi(x,0)$$
where $$\psi_n(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{a}\right)$$
The following formula allows you to evaluate this integral:
\begin{equation}\int_0^a\mathrm d x\,\frac{2}{a}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{a}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{a}\right)=\cases{1&$m=n$\\0&$m\neq n$}\label{lol}\tag{1}\end{equation}
Now, the function you are integrating is of the form $\psi(x,0)=\alpha\, \psi_1(x)+\beta\,\psi_2(x)$ where $\alpha^2+\beta^2=1$ due to normalization. So you can plug it and work it out.

But there is some nice linear algebra going that you shouldn't miss. Because of equation (1) we can treat the space of wavefunctions as a *vector space*. We can identify the basis functions as basis vectors: $$\psi_i(x)\leftrightarrow \vec e_i$$, we can decompose a general vector in terms of basis vectors (provided the basis vectors form a basis):
$$\vec v=\sum_{i=1}^Nv_i\vec e_i$$
and we can find each of these coefficients by taking the dot (inner) product
$$v_i=\langle \vec e_i,\vec v\rangle=\vec e_i\cdot\vec v$$
For the wavefunctions this dot product is replaced by an integral but it turns out a equation like (1) is enough to use a lot of the functionality that you know from vectors (linear algebra).

If we now are given a vector of the form $\vec v=\alpha\, \vec e_1+\beta\,\vec e_2$ my question is then what are $v_1,v_2$?

Comment: also thanks for the reminder about the dx's

Comment: okay i spent quite a long time on this problem last night and finally got the right answer!! thanks so much! i just have one follow up question - so it says the time independent wave function initially is a sum of two stationary states given. does this necessarily mean there will only be two constants (because two wave functions) at any given point in time? it wasn't obvious to me that there should only be two constants until I did the calculation properly, and it's still not clear to me if it should be

Comment: obvious from inspection that the time dependent wave function can always be composed of those two states with the constants and time dependence tacked on